# NSFetchedResultsController - Error - Consecutive statements on a line must be separated

Tags: swift

Please someone help me, I am getting this error and I am not able to understand why I'm getting this error. Can some one help me in this case?

[image]

Error is on the First Line.

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = { () -> <<error type>> in
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Photo")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "pin == %@", self.pin)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = []

    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.sharedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController
}
```

Comment: Please post code as actual text in your question.

Comment: Without code, how should we help you? And the error message seems to be clear. Seperate the statements on a line.

Comment: Sorry sir i have added the code.... now please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is misleading.

`NSFetchedResultsController` is also generic.

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> = { 
    let fetchRequest = ...
```